# node.js SPA with expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

For a specified route, I do `res.render('item/index');`

means I render the entire .jade file. How to load the jade template as ajax? Imagine I'm building a dashboard, when I click on item links, I want the template to load into the right column, not to reload the entire page again.

if I merely do `res.json('item/index');` I will see json data, how do I render the data into my template?

Comment: You need to do it client side if you want to load parts of a page via AJAX.

Comment: Try it out manually first using JQuery. E.g. onclick, replace div contents with AJAX response. Then, based on your preference, either go for a full-fledged JQuery solution such as [pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) or look into using a framework like angular or vue.

Comment: @PrashanthChandra I'm almost there I think, but I'm consufed with server side handlebarjs and client side. In my case do you think I really need to install handlebarsjs with node? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959973/using-ajax-with-handlebars-in-node-js

Comment: It's up to you whether you want server-side or client-side rendering. Server-side rendering means you just do `res.render()` as you were doing already. Client-side means you have to serve the jade/handlebars as a static file, like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341429/how-to-serve-rendered-jade-pages-as-if-they-were-static-html-pages-in-node-expre and then compile the jade client side, which is a bit messy honestly.

Comment: @PrashanthChandra In my ajax I specified `contentType: 'text'` and I got raw file in the response. Strange in my route I already did res.render().

Comment: Hmm, did you set your view engine in express? `app.set('view engine', 'jade');` Also I think it should be `contentType: 'text/plain'`.