# using ajax with handlebars in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a file call item.handlebars, and it can be render using `res.render('item')`.

The file look like this

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<script>
//jquery events and manipulation
</script>
```

Now I want to load that template file with ajax. How do I do that? Do I need to include handlebarjs in client side?

I tried to do an ajax call to the endpoint and this is what I got in the response

You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed [object Object]

Comment: You can fetch the raw template with ajax and render it into HTML client-side (by having handlerbars on the client) or you can create a server-side route that retrieves the already rendered file (rendering to HTML on the server).  Which to use likely depends upon whether the data that goes in the template is client-side or server-side.

Comment: it's not possible to render the file on the server side. I call to an endpoint that do res.render('item'), and what I got in the ajax response is the entire raw file.

Comment: You have to pass the desired data to `res.render()` if you want the template to be filled with the data.